# 2-D array without column number gives address?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int arr[][3] = {{1,3},{2,3},{6,7}};
cout << arr[0] << endl;   // W/O col' somehow give you the address, not the element.
cout << arr[0][0] << endl;
```

I am curious as to why `arr[0]` prints the address, not the element.
It seems like somehow it's ignoring its dereference operator.
I'd be appreciated if you could help me in terms of a pointer or in depth.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since `arr` is a two-dimensional array, `arr[0]` will give you an entire row (more precisely, the address of that row).

More precisely, since `arr` is of type `int[][3]` `arr[0]` is of type `int[3]`, which decays to `int *`. Hence, `cout << arr[0] << endl;` prints a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`array[0]` holds the address of the `array[0][0...n-1]` values so only `cout << arr[0];` prints the address since `arr[0] is the pointer to the values in arr[0][0..n-1]`

If you want specific value of an two dimensional array then you need to give both `x` and `y` index like

```
array[0][0] ... array[0][n-1]
```